# Best approach for dynamic class and package loading in Java

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic, loading

I have a factory class that creates objects of a certain type (say, `MyClass`).

The factory class belongs to a specific package and I want to dynamically switch between implementations in that package and a newer version, for testing purposes.

Say, for example, that the original package is `pack1` and the newer version is `pack2`, with class names `pack1.Factory` and `pack2.Factory`. The selection of `pack1` or `pack2` would be specified via a simple parameter in a property file. Furthermore, the `MyClass` type is common for both packages and only plain vanilla Java (i.e., no third-party libraries) should be used.

I am thinking of using `Class.forName()` for loading either `pack1.Factory` or  `pack2.Factory` (depending on the property specified) and then invoking all factory methods via reflection.

Is that the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a classical usecase for an injection of control. [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) should get you started in no time.

There is a need to have an interface such as `IFactory`, with some factory method `create`. Create two Guice modules -- in one bind `IFactory` to `pack1.Factory` and in another to `pack2.Factory`. Of course, both these factories should implement `IFactory`.

Then in the main method process your parameter that determines what factory should be used, and create an injector based on one of the modules respectively.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid reflection where ever possible. It makes your code harder to understand, harder to refactor and harder to maintain.

Instead you could let your factory class implement an interface, create an instance of the factory you want to test and call your test with this instance.

Comment: I disagree. Reflection, if used conscientiously, is fine. I think it would be quite appropriate to use it here.